# VBA - Powerpoint - Handling onClick Event

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am developing a macro for PowerPoint in vba

My goal is to have one single Sub that 1-6 shapes were manually assigned to.

So the sub is executed when a shape is clicked and should determine with a Select case statement which of the shapes was clicked exactly (and therefore run a specific script)

I am struggeling to find Code snippets that show how the onclick event is handled and how I can determine for which shape the „onclick is True“

Can you guys help me with this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you assign the following macro to each of the clickable shapes, it'll do what you're after in Slide Show view.  Select the shape, choose Insert | Action and choose run Macro: HandleShapeClick.

You may need to modify it to run on Macs because of a bug in the VBA implementation there.

If you need something like this to function in Normal or Slide view, you'll need entirely different (and considerably more complex) code.

```
Sub HandleShapeClick(oSh As Shape)

    Select Case oSh.Name
        Case Is = "Rectangle 3"
            MsgBox "You clicked Rectangle 4"
        Case Is = "Rectangle 4"
            MsgBox "You clicked Rectangle 5"
        Case Is = "Rectangle 5"
            MsgBox "You clicked Rectangle 3"
        ' etc, for each add'l clickable shape
        
    End Select
    
End Sub
```